# Secure private docker-registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

How to you setup a **private** secure docker-registry.

I have installed via [helm](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/docker-registry)

Now how can I make it secure(TLS certs), so I can push and pull to the registry from docker and from kubernetes deployment?

I can see that there is a Helm configuration:

```
tlsSecretName   Name of secret for TLS certs
```

***Update - current status***:
I was able to get [cert-manager](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager) working and install with TLS:

```
helm install stable/docker-registry --set tlsSecretName=example-com-tls
```

*I am not strong in certificates - but I am unclear about the following*:
**1.** 
Can I now create an Ingress(with a secret to cert) that will only accept incomming request with that certificate? I will look at the suggested link from @xzesstence tomorrow
**2.** 
I guess I need to tell `docker push` where to find the certificate?
Maybe this(**I will try this tomorrow**): https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/

Comment: This in my opinion can be a broad topic, security can be applied on a network level, application level, firewall, etc., please be precise where you are pointing at.

Comment: indeed @Vishrant but in this case i guess its obviously for a docker user. he wants to secure the service layer to run over TLS

Comment: @xzesstence oh I see an edit just before your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the official Docker Tutorials
https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/

and especially the point
**Get a certificate**

So overall in short, you need to get a certificate and place it in /certs (or change the folder mount of the following docker run command -v /cert).
Also check the certificate name, either rename to domain.crt or change the filename in the docker run command

then run

```html
docker run -d \
  --restart=always \
  --name registry \
  -v "$(pwd)"/certs:/certs \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:443 \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key \
  -p 443:443 \
  registry:2
```

If you don't have a certificate, you can use letsencrypt
https://letsencrypt.org/

Maybe you want to checkout this startscript with letsencrypt certs. (untested from my side)
The advantage of this is, that you have the letsencrypt service integrated which can renew the license automatically
https://gist.github.com/PieterScheffers/63e4c2fd5553af8a35101b5e868a811e

Edit:
Since you are using Docker on a Kubernetes Cluster checkout this great tutorial
https://medium.com/@jmarhee/in-cluster-docker-registry-with-tls-on-kubernetes-758eecfe8254

Comment: Thanks, really good suggestion. I am running on kubernetres and using Helm. Regarding certs I am thinking of using stable/cert-manager

Comment: I have updated my question a bit inc. using a certificate manager on k8s. I will try looking at creating an Ingress as in the link you suggested. Thanks and please let me know :-)